# How to call function from JPanel from JTabbedPane on switching corresponding tab?

Tags: java, swing, events, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I've JTabbedPane tb and I've added 5 JPanels in it as illustrated in below code. Those 5 Panels are separate Java Classes put in same package. Each of these Classes have function named **refreshTable()**. How can I call that function whenever I switch to corresponding tab?

```
        JTabbedPane tb=new JTabbedPane();
        tb.add("विक्री",new ReportPanel());
        tb.add("बिल",new BillPanel());
        tb.add("ग्राहक",new CustomerPanel());
        tb.add("वर्तमानपत्र/मासिक",new ProductPanel());
        tb.add("सेटींग्स",new Settings());

        tb.addChangeListener((ChangeEvent e) -> {  
            // Here I want to call function refreshTable() from switched JPanel Class.
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I call that function whenever I switch to corresponding tab?

You can add a `ChangeListener` to the JTabbedPane.

An event will be generated every time a new tab is selected. You can then get the panel on the current tab and invoke the `refreshTable()` method for that panel.

You can read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a ChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/changelistener.html) for a simple example of how the listener works.